# How to sort product displays by price using search api sorts?

Tags: 7, commerce, search

Actually I want to do the same behaviour as in commerce kickstart 2 for sorting my products by price. I'm using [search api](https://drupal.org/project/search_api_db), [search api db](https://drupal.org/project/search_api_db), [search api sorts](https://drupal.org/project/search_api_sorts), [search api ranges](https://drupal.org/project/search_api_ranges), [commerce search api](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_search_api) modules. I have created indexed node view with views and it is working fine. I can range nodes by price... I indexed the field "field_tshirt_commerce_price_amount_decimal_asc" with my node (my product type is called tshirt). And I want to see it in my sorts, but it just writes "There are currently no fields for which sorts can be displayed." Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

my solution is:

1. Fields Tab: in Related Fields section add Product-Price multi field
2. Field sTab: check field_product:commerce_price:amount_decimal for index (integer)
3. Filters Tab: enable aggregated fields.
4. Filters Tab: add aggregated field: name - your custom label, type of aggregation - first, Contained fields - Price > Amount (decimal)
5. Fields Tab: check your new aggregated field for index (integer)
6. Sorts Tab: now your custom aggregated field available for sort

Be sure you are using latest dev version of the [Search API sorts](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_sorts) because of the https://drupal.org/node/2202093 issue.

Comment: I followed your steps and it still doesn't work...

Comment: what exactly doesn't work? in my project this solution works fine